# Returning Mono and Flux error always returns 500

Tags: java, exception, mono, spring-webflux, flux

I'm still trying to learn how WebFlux exceptions work, as far as I understand, when returning an object in a Flux or Mono, the consumer should receive the same exception which was sent from the server.

However, when I return an HTTPException 401 inside a Mono for example, the response body I receive in the consumer is different from what I sent, I read a 500 Internal Server error instead of 401.

Here is a simple controller class I made for the question

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(
        path="/getExceptionMono",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> getException(){
        return Mono.error(new HTTPException(401));
    }
}
```

Here is the consumer :

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Component
public class ReactiveDemoConsumer implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/getExceptionMono";
        WebClient.create(url)
            .get()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .subscribe(value -> System.err.println("Received String: " + value),
                        err -> System.err.println("Received error " + err));

    }
}
```

This is the console log of the consumer

```
Received error org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from GET http://localhost:8080/getExceptionMono
```

How do I pass my exception so that the consumer will see the original one which I passed in the Mono?
Hope my question is clear, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use onStatus and check the response code?

Mono<Person> result = client.get()
        .uri("/persons/{id}", id).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> ...)
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> ...)
        .bodyToMono(Person.class);

Comment: Just tried the suggestion, it just skips the 4xx predicate straight to the 5xx, printed the response and it returns "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse@c7a55c43"

Comment: @EdenDupont Please go through my answer once. I hope it clarifies your doubts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the correct way to return a 4xx response from an application.
**Any kind of exception thrown within the application will be wrapped by WebClientResponseException and be received as a 500 Internal Server Error on the client side.**

One way to change that is having an exception handler in your controller like this:

```
  @ExceptionHandler({UnsupportedMediaTypeException.class})
  public ResponseEntity<String> exceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.getMessage());
  }
```

Another way is to have a global exception handler in your code:
(here Ex1 is something like HTTPException)

```
@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
    ServerHttpResponse httpResponse = exchange.getResponse();
    setResponseStatus(httpResponse, ex);
    return httpResponse.writeWith(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
      DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = httpResponse.bufferFactory();
      try {
        //Not displaying any error msg to client for internal server error
        String errMsgToSend = (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) ? "" : ex.getMessage();
        return bufferFactory.wrap(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(errMsgToSend));
      } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        return bufferFactory.wrap(new byte[0]);
      }
    }));
  }

  private void setResponseStatus(ServerHttpResponse httpResponse, Throwable ex) {
    if (ex instanceof Ex1 || ex instanceof Ex2 || ex instanceof Ex3) {
      httpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
      httpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can re-write your controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(
        path="/getExceptionMono",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> getException(){
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().build());
    }
}
```

Then in webclient code, you can do something like this:

```
webClient
 .get()
 .uri("/some/url")
 .exchange()
 .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
     if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
        //do something and return some mono
     }
     else if(clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
        //do something and return some mono
     }
     else {
       //do something and return some mono  
     }
});
```

Comment: Things seem to get a bit clearer now, so the correct way of sending objects is also wrapped by a ResponseEntity, say I wanted to send a string, it would look like this in the controller :
 public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getException(){
   return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().body(new String("MyString")));
 }

is it correct?

Comment: if you return objects directly, spring will set the response code to 200 by default. if you need something else like 202 accepted or 204 no content, you need to return response entity